# Beads NullPointerException before program even begins?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, processing

I'm writing a random loop player in Processing using the Beads library and importing some of my own loops. Every time I run the code, it gives me a NullPointerException. The files are in the same directory as the sketch, and all filenames are spelled correctly. I've tried using the internal debugger and it always breaks, even when I set the breakpoint on the first line. (I've also tried rebooting on the off chance that that would fix it. It didn't.)

This is my code (not all of it, just the relevant stuff). The class name is Randomiser.

```java
import beads.*;
import org.jaudiolibs.beads.*;
import java.util.Random;

// samples
SamplePlayer rhythm1; 
SamplePlayer rhythm2;
SamplePlayer rhythm3;
SamplePlayer rhythm4;
SamplePlayer currentRhythm;

//files
String r1file;
String r2file;
String r3file;
String r4file;

//arrays
ArrayList rhythmArray;

AudioContext ac; // to hear output
Gain gain; // to change volume

void setup() { 
  size(300, 300); 
  background(255);
  r1file = sketchPath("") + "Rhythm1_80BPM.wav";
  r2file = sketchPath("") + "Rhythm2_80BPM.wav";
  r3file = sketchPath("") + "Rhythm3_80BPM.wav";
  r4file = sketchPath("") + "Rhythm4_80BPM.wav";
  // set up arrays
  rhythmArray  = new ArrayList<SamplePlayer>();
  try {
    rhythm1 = new SamplePlayer(ac, new Sample(r1file));
    rhythm2 = new SamplePlayer(ac, new Sample(r2file));
    rhythm3 = new SamplePlayer(ac, new Sample(r3file));
    rhythm4 = new SamplePlayer(ac, new Sample(r4file));
  }
  catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    exit();
  } 
  //instantiate arraylists
  rhythmArray.add(rhythm1);
  rhythmArray.add(rhythm2);
  rhythmArray.add(rhythm3);
  rhythmArray.add(rhythm4);
}

void draw() { 
  button();
}

void mouseClicked() {
  if (mouseX>113 && mouseX<193 && mouseY>140 && mouseY<220) randomise();
}
```

This is the stacktrace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at beads.UGen.setOutsToPause(Unknown Source)
    at beads.UGen.pause(Unknown Source)
    at beads.Static.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at beads.SamplePlayer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at beads.SamplePlayer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Randomiser.setup(Randomiser.java:81)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2425)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1547)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:313)
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: It's not all the relevant stuff. You don't even mention the name of your class. Is it 'Randomiser' by any chance?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, it is. I've edited the post.

Comment: so what do you mean, NPE before the application executes? Your stacktrace states it is thrown at line 81 of that class. But, are you using applets? or what is PApplet?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out my problem.

Firstly, my AudioContext was not initialised in the setup() function, which was confusing the compiler, as it was referencing ac when I was initialising r1file, r2file, r3file and r4file in setup(). I fixed this by moving my ac initialisation to the beginning of the setup() function.

Secondly, I was using MP3 files, not WAV files, which Beads can't tolerate. I converted the MP3s to WAVs and imported them again, which solved the problem entirely.

Everything in the setup() function is the same except for this section:

```java
void setup() { 
  ac = new AudioContext();
  size(300, 300); 
  background(255);
  r1file = sketchPath("") + "Rhythm1_80BPM.wav";
  r2file = sketchPath("") + "Rhythm2_80BPM.wav";
  r3file = sketchPath("") + "Rhythm3_80BPM.wav";
  r4file = sketchPath("") + "Rhythm4_80BPM.wav";
```